# C Recursively checking a Palindrome

Tags: c, recursion

I've got an assignment where I need to check if a given string is a palindrome or not recursively.

E.G. :

```
aD1Da // returns 1
asd1s // returns 0
```

The function signature needs to look like this:

```
int isPolindrom(char str[]);
```

Which means I'm getting only one parameter. I managed to build a solution using a static variable (The function will be called more than once, so we were instructed not to use static variables, though my solution works for more than 1 call).

My solution:

```
static flag = 0; 
int isPolindrom(char str[])
{
    static int pos = 1;
    if (flag == 1) { 
        pos = 1; // Reset
        flag = 0; // Reset
    }
    if (pos >= strlen(str)) { 
        flag = 1; 
        return 1; 
    }
    if (*str == *(str + strlen(str) - pos)) { 
        pos++; 
        return  isPolindrom(str + 1); 
    }
    else return 0; 
}
```

It's also possible using a secondary function, but I was wondering if and how is it possible to do this **without** static variables and **without** writing secondary functions.

In the automatic tests they are sending me the string as a constant string. For example:

```
isPolindrom("abcba")
```

Comment: @SMA.: Possible.. will add it.

Comment: By mutating the string.

Comment: Ahh good idea @DavidBrowne-Microsoft!

Comment: without writing a new secondary function.. @snr

Comment: First you write a wrong solution, than you call me a noob,  than you add additional solution which was wronger than the first one. and than you delete your answer. @snr . Nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a new string inside `palindrome()`.

```
int palindrome(char *str)
{ 
    int len= strlen(str);
    if(len<=1)
      return true;
    char a=str[0];
    char b=str[len-1];
    char *newstr=malloc(len-2+1);
    for(int i=1;i<len-1;i++)
        newstr[i-1] = str[i];
    newstr[len-2]='\0';

    int res = (a==b && palindrome(newstr));
    free(newstr);
    return res;
}
```

and call it as

```
 palin("abcba");
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible. Assuming that ***string is null terminated and is mutable*** we will do this

```
int isPolindrom(char s[])
{
    
    int l = 0;
    while(s[l]) l++;
    if(l == 2)
       return s[0]==s[1];
    if(l <= 1)
       return 1;

    char c=s[l-1];
    s[l-1]=0;
    
    int result = (s[0]==c) && isPolindrom(s+1);
    
    s[l-2]=c;
    return result ;
}
```

Though it doesn't change the passed argument - we are modifying it internally. That's why modifiable sting requirement was needed.

#### After edit:

Note my earlier answer was considering that you couldn't use any function but as OP made it clear we can easily use standard library functions like `malloc` etc. That's why this solution using dynamically allocated memory.

With the given constraint

```
int isPolindrom(const char *s)
{
    int l = 0;
    while(s[l]) l++;
    if(l == 2)
      return s[0]==s[1];
    if(l == 1)
      return 1;
    
    char *ss =  malloc(l-1);
    if( ss == NULL ){
       perror("Error in malloc");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<l-2;i++)
    ss[i]=s[i+1];
    ss[l-2]=0;
    int p = (s[0]==s[l-1]) && isPolindrom(ss);
    
    free(ss);
    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my take on this:

1. check if string must be palindrome (i.e. less than 2 chars), if yes - return true
2. if no, check if `first == last`, if yes - recursive call with the inner string

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool is_palindrome(char * str){
    // end conditions
    if (!str)
        return false;
    if (strlen(str) < 2)
        return true;

    // check first vs. last
    if (str[0] == str[strlen(str) - 1]){
        // remove first & last chars (copy to array to allow this)
        char tmp_arr[strlen(str) - 1];
        strncpy(tmp_arr, str+1, strlen(str) - 2);
        tmp_arr[strlen(str) - 2] = '\0';
        return is_palindrome(tmp_arr);

        /* if string was mutable - this would be easier:

                str[strlen(str) - 1] = '\0';
                return is_palindrome(str + 1);
        */
    }

    return false;
}

int main(){
    printf(is_palindrome("abcddcba") ? "true\n" : "false\n");
    printf(is_palindrome("abcddcbaa") ? "true\n" : "false\n");
    printf(is_palindrome("abcd   dcba") ? "true\n" : "false\n");
    while(1);
    return 0;
}
```